# How add the output of a random string array method onto a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a method that randomly generates a string array and returns it. I want to be able to put that string array in a node as part of a linked list of these randomly generated string arrays. I also want it so that if I were to use an append method it would pull a randomly generated array from my method onto the new node. What would be the best way to do that?

Edit: For clarification each node is going to hold an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
List<String[]> myList = new LinkedList<>();